# Что нужно знать чтобы стать Junior Java Developer?

Tags: java

хочу начать изучать програмирование, а именно джаву. Вот хотел по этому поводу узнать что я должен знать для юниора. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

1. java синтаксис
2. java core
3. Алгоритмы + типы данных + collections
4. multithreading (что-то знать про Concurrent)
5. Уметь делать простые SQL запросы
6. Spring Hibernate или аналоги, можно и без этого, но сложно будет найти вакансию.
7. Тестирование, хоть как-то. Может быть не must have, но лишним не будет. Но свой код тестировать уметь нужно.
8. Git или аналог
9. Будет плюсом Docker

А вообще открываете вакансию на hh, и там будет стек.

Comment: Спасибо, а что с математикой? Нужна ли она?

Comment: @holodholod Пожалуйста, разве что для общего развития. Сам пока только учусь, но смотря на реальные проекты, понимаю, что они имеют мало общего с тем, что делаем во время начального обучения.